# How can I choose to show only unequal data result and minus or blind equal data result?

Tags: robotframework

Here's my robot code

There are 22 records on both tables but only 1 record has an unequal data I would like to show that result and minus or blind an equal data result.

```
 connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}
 @{queryResultsA}=   Query  Select count (*) from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A order by SECURITY_ID
 Log  ${queryResultsA}
 @{queryResultsB}=   Query  Select count (*) from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B order by SECURITY_ID
 Log  ${queryResultsB}

should not contain match    ${queryResultsB}  ${queryResultsA}
```

Comment: please add record samples

Comment: Did you try sorting both tables and comparing line by line?

Comment: The SQL `count()` returns just a number, the # of records that fulfill the condition; show the actual query you're using. The schemas in the 2 tables are the same (at least in the columns your interested in), I presume? Finally, these types of checks are usually/better done on the DB level (through queries) - that's the purpose and the power of the DB engine.

Answer (score 2):

1. ***Using For Loop***

   ```
    # Assuming your table has values like this
   @{queryResultsA}=   Create List     a   b   c   d   e
   @{queryResultsB}=   Create List     a   z   c   d   e

   ${Length}=  Get Length      ${queryResultsA}
   ${count}=   Set Variable

   :FOR     ${count}   IN RANGE     ${Length}      
   \       Run Keyword If  '@{queryResultsA}[${count}]'!='@{queryResultsB}[${count}]'      Log To Console      @{queryResultsA}[${count}] @{queryResultsB}[${count}]
   ```

   ***OUTPUT***
   `b z`
2. ***Using SET***

   ```
   ${z} =  Evaluate    (set(${queryResultsA}) - set(${queryResultsB}))
   Log     ${z}
   ```

   ***OUTPUT***
   `b`

   Note the difference here Set B is subtracted from  Set A so whatever not matched in set A will be the output.