# Robotframework String Operator IN

Tags: robotframework

How can i check (short code) if some string contain another in Robotframework?
(like "IN" in Python)

Like this is working:

```
${aaax}=     set variable  aaa aa ba baavaa
${aaaxx}=    set variable  aaa aba baavaa
${aba}=      set variable  aba

${res1}=     run keyword and return status  should contain  ${aaax}     ${aba}
${res2}=     run keyword and return status  should contain  ${aaaxx}    ${aba}

log to console  ${EMPTY}
log to console  res1: ${res1}
log to console  res2: ${res2}
```

Anyone have a better solution? like "${aba}" IN "${aaax}" or something like that working?

Comment: How do you define `better`? What's wrong with `should contain`?

Comment: @BryanOakley I believe the problem is that the `Should Contain` will fail the test and the OP only needs the result without failing the test. That is why it is used along with `run keyword and return status`, and I think getting rid of this part would mean the "better" solution.

Comment: probably you looking for **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54094771/5400362)** solution, it might help you, two option using 1. Lists and 2. set

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword from the BuiltIn library to simply use the Python `in` operator.

```
*** Variables ***
${aaax}     aaa aa ba baavaa
${aaaxx}    aaa aba baavaa'
${aba}      aba

*** Test Cases ***
String Contains
    ${res1}=    Evaluate    $aaax in $aba
    ${res2}=    Evaluate    $aba in $aaaxx
    Log To Console    ${res1}
    Log To Console    ${res2}
```

Comment: This would be better if you wrote it as `$aaaz in $aba`. Your answer will fail if `{aaax}` or `${aba}` contained a single quote.

Comment: @BryanOakley Indeed, it will fail if one `'` is included in a string. Also it fails with `Evaluating expression 'aaa aa ba baavaa in aba' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)` in every case without the quotes around the variables. So all in all I would say this solution is limited to work with strings without single quotes.

Comment: Like I said in my other comment, if you use `$aaaz` instead of `${aaaz}` in your `Evaluate` statement you will avoid that issue, and this code work work for any strings.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh, sorry I have overlooked the missing `{`, focused on the missing quotes. Thanks for pointing out. I will modify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use also [Set Variable If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) keyword combining it with `in`:

```
${res1}=     Set Variable If   $aba in $aaax    True    False
${res2}=     Set Variable If   $aba in $aaaxx    True    False
```